# Connecting to MySQL using Groovy

Tags: mysql, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database using the below Groovy code on MAC OS 10.10.5 Yosemite

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

try{
    def dbURL = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila'
    def dbUserName = 'root'
    def dbPassword = 'Orange@27'
    def dbDriver = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    log.info('Good')
    def db = Sql.newInstance(dbURL,dbUserName,dbPassword,dbDriver)
}catch(Exception e){
    log.info('DB Error')
    log.info(e.getMessage())
}finally{

}
```

But when I execute this code, I see the below message

```
Sat Aug 13 15:09:14 EDT 2016:INFO:Good
Sat Aug 13 15:09:14 EDT 2016:INFO:DB Error
Sat Aug 13 15:09:14 EDT 2016:INFO:No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila
```

I have kept the `groovy-sql-2.1.1.jar`, `mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar` inside the folder location `/Applications/SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/ext/`

Could you please help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: How are you launching it?

Comment: @chrylis I launch SoapUI using this file /Applications/SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/soapui.command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use a JDBC driver you need to *register* it. There are a number of ways to do this:

### Using DriverManager

You can register a JDBD driver with a `DriverManager`:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager

DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver())

// Remaining Groovy code here
```

### Class.forName

Kind of a hack, but you can also dynamically load the driver's class:

```
Class.forName('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')

// Remaining Groovy code here
```

### Groovy Grape

Because you're using Soap UI to run the Groovy code, this option may not work for you, but here it is for completeness:

```
@Grab('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39')
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)

// Remaining Groovy code here
```

Comment: When I use Class.forName('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver') I get "NoClassFoundException" and with below lines I get "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila"

import java.sql.DriverManager

DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver())

Comment: Then you haven't placed the MySQL jar file in the classpath. `/Applications/SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/ext/` must not be the correct folder.

Comment: Copying the file mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar from /Applications/SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/ext/ to /Applications/SoapUI-5.2.1/lib resolved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- User libraries should be copied under SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext directory, In this case, copy the mysql jdbc library in the above directory.
- SoapUI registers jdbc drivers differently. Use below statement to register as per its [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html#10-Use-a-JDBC-Driver-from-inside-a-groovy-script):

```
//Register driver
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
//Get the sql instance using the connection details.
Sql.newInstance(dbURL,dbUserName,dbPassword)
```