# Drop tables through Jenkins

Tags: mysql, jenkins, ddl

I am using `drop` command to delete multiple tables in MySQL Database.

I want to fire drop command through Jenkins for these tables.

How can I connect Jenkins with DB to fire Drop commands?

Answer (score 2):

I would write a Groovy script to do what you want to (i.e. drop tables):

[Connecting to MySQL using Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936206/connecting-to-mysql-using-groovy)

Then, I would install a Groovy Jenkins plugin and call that Groovy script to do the drop whenever you want to - post build is one opportunity:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin

There are other ways, but this is how I would do it.

*EDIT* Since you asked for how to drop table in Groovy - try something like this:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root","sms003", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

//Drop table if it already exists
sql.execute('drop TABLE users')
```

Comment: Thanks mikeb.....But after reading Groovy code, where I have to add Drop command in Groovy code....Or any other pointers?